# Is there anything that can react with molecular gaseous nitrogen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reactivity

I am looking for something to react with nitrogen in the air. Is there any substance that can react fast with molecular nitrogen at room temperature?

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen#Reactions)

> Elemental lithium reacts ("burns") in an atmosphere of $\ce{N2}$ to give lithium nitride:
>   $$\ce{6Li + N2 → 2 Li3N}$$
>
> Magnesium also burns in nitrogen, forming magnesium nitride.
>   $$\ce{3 Mg + N2 → Mg3N2}$$

Comment: Those reactions will only take place in "pure nitrogen" not air. The OP asked about reactions in air that react with nitrogen.

Comment: [While lithium reacts with nitrogen at room temperature,  reaction between magnesium and nitrogen require large amount of heat.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/Main_Group_Reactions/Reactions_of_Main_Group_Elements_with_Nitrogen)